# how can i install and use openssl on mac?

Tags: openssl

the task says:

1. Use OpenSSL to calculate the following user names and passwords (4 pts): • Anaga:happy666
   • Maria:12345678 • Joseph:q1w2e3r4 • Stephan:1234asdf

i am not sure how to install and use openssl. i have tried to install openssl but it is only a folder on my computer so dont know what to do next.[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is on your picture is just source code of openssl. I think macOS have built-in openssl already. Try to open the terminal application and just run

```
openssl
```

to check it is already installed on your system.

According to your task

> Use OpenSSL to calculate the following user names and passwords

it's unclear. What do you want to calculate? Hash or what?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is the simplest one: do nothing. macOS has shipped with OpenSSL preinstalled since 2000.

You can download a binary distribution of OpenSSL. The OpenSSL project does not itself publish binary releases, but they maintain a [list of third-party resources that publish OpenSSL binaries](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries).

You can install it using [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/openssl/summary).

You can install it using [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openssl@1.1).

You can compile it yourself. You already downloaded the source code, so all you need is to follow the instructions in the `INSTALL.md` file you are showing in your screenshot. I assume that, since you chose to use an inofficial development version, you may run into some bugs.